# PyCharm3 Live template not working at all

Tags: python, templates, code-snippets

I just switched from `Eclipse/PyDev` to `PyCharm 3 CE`. I can't get the live templates working any ways. Followed every documentation I can find online like this:
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/live-templates.html

And the builtin python template `super(Generates a 'super' call)` does not work either.
By "not working", I meant that when editing a python file in PyCharm and typing the abbreviation, the popup snippets list does not include the live templates, even though they are under the Python template group.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I am using PyCharm 3.1 Professional (evaluation version) and am having the same issue.
 However, using Ctrl+J will bring up templates as will Code -> Insert Live Template. It is also possible to start typing a code snippet and then press Ctrl+J to see a filtered list of templates.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to also select the "context"...

[image]